# How to get filtered data from angular js table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have created an angularjs table with the help of an array.
Below is the reference code :-

HTML code:-

```
<table align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Session Code</th>
            <th>Session Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" title="Enter First name here to filter data" ng-model="firstNameText"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name.." title="Enter Last name here to filter data" ng-model="lastNameText"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="tr in Names | filter:{First_x0020_Name:firstNameText,Last_x0020_Name:lastNameText}" style="cursor:pointer">
        <td data-ng-cloak ng-click="getInfo($index,$event)">{{tr.First_x0020_Name}}</td>
        <td data-ng-cloak ng-click="getInfo($index,$event)">{{tr.Last_x0020_Name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When you clicked on the table data of a row you get alert of the First Name and Last Name of row that you have clicked.

Below is the code when clicked on the table data.

```
$scope.getInfo = function(index,$event){
    alert($scope.Names[index].First_x0020_Name + ' , ' + $scope.Names[index].Last_x0020_Name);
}
```

It works when the data is not filtered.

But when I filtered data using input in table header and click on the table data, it gives wrong name and surname.

I want to get the first name and last name of the person that I have clicked even it is filtered.

I know that the **getInfo** function that I am using gets the data from non - filtered **names** array.

How can I use the filtered angularjs table then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of index you can pass row object to your function

html

```
 <td data-ng-cloak ng-click="getInfo(tr,$event)">{{tr.First_x0020_Name}}</td>
```

js

```
$scope.getInfo = function(row,$event){
    alert(row.First_x0020_Name + ' , ' + row.Last_x0020_Name);
}
```

Comment: Passing the row reference directly was a good idea. Nice solution indeed !!

Comment: I am glad I could help.